# How to save mongoose virtuals

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Can anyone provide example how to save mongoose virtuals for db associations usage?

Already have this within model:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    googleId: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    credits: {type: Number, default: 0},
});

userSchema.virtual('advertisements', {
    ref: 'advertisements',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: '_id',
    justOne: false,
    options: { sort: { name: -1 }, limit: 5 }
  });

mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

Within docs there is  info about data population and [retrieval](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals), but how should look like proper save?

Does it have to be `user.advertisements.localfield  = localfield` or so?
Or how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Virtuals are document properties that you can get and set but that do
>   not get persisted to MongoDB. The getters are useful for formatting or
>   combining fields, while setters are useful for de-composing a single
>   value into multiple values for storage.

It's mean we can use Virtuals for only data preparation for example we can merge `first name` and `last name` or populate the document with reference.

Answer (score 1):

> Mongoose supports virtual attributes. Virtual attributes are attributes
>   that are convenient to have around but that **do not get persisted to mongodb**.

You cannot save virtual data, its only getter